# Is it possible for wp_mail to sometimes fail?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a simple function that uses wp_mail, like:

```
$headers = "From: $myName <$myEmail>" . "\r\n";
wp_mail( $myToEmail, $mySubject, $myMessage, $myHeaders );
```

When I put this code onto a site, it seems there are sometimes when the email does not send, but I do not see any way to replicate the issue and it generally works.

Where are potential points of failure?

Is it possible the email is failing on the server side occasionally?

Comment: have you checked your server log?

Answer (score -1):

**You need to use WP_mail() function to your contact form.You can use this way**

see this is example:

```
headers = "From: $myName <$myEmail>" . "\r\n";
//Here put your Validation and send mail
$sent = wp_mail( $myToEmail, $mySubject, $myMessage, $myHeaders );
if($sent) {

}//message sent!
else  {

}//message wasn't sent
```